# How to use wildcard in sqlx query in Go?

Tags: go, sqlx

I'm using sqlx with mysql database and want to query `author` table for names which start with certain letters. Here is the query:

```
sqlx.DB.Select(&authors, "SELECT * FROM author WHERE first_name LIKE ?% OR last_name LIKE ?%", letter,letter)
```

but I get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
>   near '% OR last_name LIKE ?%'

I've looked in the docs for examples of `LIKE` queries but could not find any. So wondering how can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have `%` in there, wouldn't those be `?`, `?` or `:p1`, `:p2`, `$1`, `$2` (whatever the MySQL parameter placeholder is)

I would do like this:

```
sqlx.DB.Select(&authors, "SELECT * FROM author WHERE first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?",
    letter+"%",letter+"%")
```

The wildcard `%` should be part of the parameter string.

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is using CONCAT:

```
sqlx.DB.Select(&authors, "SELECT * FROM author WHERE first_name LIKE CONCAT(?, '%') OR last_name LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')", letter, letter)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL string concatenation:

```
SELECT * FROM author
WHERE first_name LIKE ? || '%' OR last_name LIKE ? || '%'
```

Comment: Yes. But then the SQL would be less flexible (say you wanted to search for an exact match or another wildcard pattern).